# "This policy" words (in Mozilla Community Participation Guidelines) with no specific policy mentioned right before. What does it refer to?

Tags: contract-law, employment

[Mozilla Community Participation Guidelines](https://www.mozilla.org/en-US/about/governance/policies/participation/):

> Version 3.1 – Updated January 16, 2020
>
> Modifications to these Guidelines
>
> Mozilla may amend the guidelines from time to time and may also vary
> the procedures it sets out where appropriate in a particular case.
> Your agreement to comply with the guidelines will be deemed agreement
> to any changes to it. **This policy** does not form part of any Mozilla
> employee’s contract of employment or otherwise have contractual
> effect.

Which policy is above referred to? Modifications? If so, does it mean adherence to Guidlines is fixed to version current at the moment of commencement of employment? Otherwise? It seems to me it cannot refer to Guidelines as before that paragraph it is stated:

> Mozilla staff in violation of these guidelines may be subject to
> further consequences, such as disciplinary action, up to and including
> termination of employment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"This policy" is referring to the Mozilla Community Participation Guidelines as amended (basically a Terms of Service (TOS) agreement).

> If so, does it mean adherence to Guidlines is fixed to version current
> at the moment of commencement of employment?

Not really. It means that Mozilla Community Participation Guidelines are primarily guidelines for members of the general public who are not employees, and that different unstated policies delivered to employees are what govern employees instead. There are consequences for Mozilla employees failing to honor the current version of the Mozilla Community Participation Guidelines, but those consequences are set forth in an employment contract with the employees rather than being limited to the consequences and procedures set forth in the Mozilla Community Participation Guidelines for members of the general public who aren't employees.

Comment: Thank you. However, why is it mentioned in "Modifications" paragraph? AFAIK paragraph titles may not carry a legal meaning, still...

Comment: @Martian2020 It is very likely that it is redundant. It was previously mentioned with respect to the original policy and this reiterates that it also applies to the modifications.

Comment: Pardon my curiosity, where is it mentioned previously? I've searched for "employee" and "staff" and have not found similar phrase.

Comment: @Martian2020 In the locations noted with footnote 1.

Comment: It says there "in addition". From my understanding I do not agree with you here. But thank you for the answer as a whole again ! P.S. I noted in the document e-mail for queries, I've sent an e-mail after I posted that question, maybe I will receive a response.

Comment: I got a response from Mozilla, it is basically same as your answer "“This policy” refers to the current version of the CPG adopted by Mozilla."